# Foreign Travelers to Schengen

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration

I just want to ask how does foreign travelers get their immigration done when they travel by bus or train from one country to another in Schengen countries. Does Train/Bus stop at the border for immigration or how is it done?

Comment: _Inside_ Schengen? The border is almost invisible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No traveller clears immigration at a usual internal Schengen border, EU citizen or not. For all intents and purposes regarding travel the Schengen area can be seen as a single country. Almost every time nobody shows their passport or visa and there is nobody they could show them to.

Note that there are some national visas which don't allow travel to all Schengen countries all the time. Those are not checked routinely at the border. However, the national police has the right to conduct checks a few kilometers around the border. In that case buses can be stopped. Checks in trains are usually conducted while moving between two stations (usually they just pick a few passengers for a spot check). Those are however rare.

For reference, this is what a typical intra-Schengen border looks like. Most aren't manned nor are there any other permanent structures or buildings except the sign:

[image: Schengen border]

Comment: Sometimes there are signs with a summary of the speed limits, which still differ from country to country. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zeichen_393.svg

Comment: It looks a lot like the building to the right of the "France" sign and the red building behind the two cars are in fact the permanent structures of the erstwhile border control post, though. The traffic island that may look like a roundabout in the picture is also part of the former border control arrangements.

Comment: @HenningMakholm [Probably right](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.3419993,3.9708769,364m/data=!3m1!1e3), this is just the first CC0 image I could find. Most borders I have been to only have abandoned buildings if any. The linked map shows that other borders in that area don't have any buildings.

Comment: @HenningMakholm on the other hand, on the controlled-access highways, in my experience at least, it's quite common for evidence of former border posts to be difficult to spot.  I suspect most international buses use those sorts of roads.